# FPDF Variable in header function

Tags: php, variables, scope, fpdf

I'm trying to get a variable into the header function of FPDF. I know it's a scoping problem, but I'm not sure how to pass in the variable $branch

```html
$branch = $_POST['branch'];

class PDF extends FPDF
{
  function Header()
  {
  $this->Cell(150);
  $this->Cell(30,10,$branch,0,0,'C');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You have `$branch` outside of the class ...

You could include `global $branch;` in your function to access it.

```
function Header()
{
    global $branch;

    $this->Cell(150);
    $this->Cell(30,10,$branch,0,0,'C');
}
```

However, it would be a better idea to call the function with the `$branch` as an argument.

```
function Header($branch)
{
    $this->Cell(150);
    $this->Cell(30,10,$branch,0,0,'C');
}

// $pdf->Header($_POST['branch'])
```

Comment: I had my global outside the class - appreciate your answer 1+

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
$GLOBALS["branch"] = $_POST['branch'];
```

and in your function:

```
$this->Cell(30,10,$GLOBALS["branch"],0,0,'C');
```

Comment: Thanks! It's the only one that worked for me!

Answer (score 3):

I solve it using something like this

```
class pdf extends FPDF {
    public $custom;
    public function __construct($custom) {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->custom = $custom;
    }

    function Header() {
        $this->Cell(190, 10, $this->custom, 1,1,'C');
    }
}

$pdf = new pdf("Hello World");
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Best solution there is. Thans!

Answer (score 1):

```
$branch = 'XYZ';

$GLOBALS["branch"] = $branch;

function Header($branch) { $this->Cell(30,10,$branch,0,0,'C'); }
```

Answer (score 1):

```php
$branch = "branch name";

$this->Cell(30,10,'.$branch.',0,0,'C');
```

Use PHP concatenation operator (`.`), then pass the variable.

Comment: This as nothing to do with OP issue.